# Can I build a real state advertising website using drupal?

Tags: drupal

I want to build a commercial website such as craiglist but specific for real state business, I was wonder if I could use Drupal to do it .. I ask this because I want to use one CMS rather than going with a scratch or framework approach, and I don't know anyone. So to save me time I need to know if Drupal could be a good choice.

Best,

Comment: Yes. -- Please clarify your question to ask what you really want to know.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you can. Drupal is very versatile and capable. It already has many modules that will bring you different peaces of functionality you can assemble to get what you need.

Make sure to have a look at [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck), [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Also, here is a [list of 40 essential Drupal modules](http://www.nicklewis.org/40-essential-drupal-6-modules).

The http://drupalrealestate.com site is a case study of Drupal and it's powerful contributed module base.

If you're new to Drupal, you're surely be interested in resources:

- [Learn By The Drop](http://learnbythedrop.com/)
- [Lullabot articles](http://www.lullabot.com/articles)
- [The Drupal Real Estate group](http://groups.drupal.org/real-estate)

Answer (score 1):

I think, Drupal is a good choice for this purpose.

If you are still doubt, you can check [sites about real estate](http://www.drupalsites.net/search/node/real%20estate), which are built on Drupal.

Some examples:  http://www.garyfeldman.com/, http://www.stockmanngroup.com/, http://www.bayrealty.com/.